# Android dynamic user interface

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android development and I am troubled with something.

I want to create a user interface first and I have a question regarding adding dynamic fields. I am already using XML to setup my interface but I don't know how to proceed.

For example, the user can select 1 2 3 or 4 and based on the selection I would like the dialog box to show that number of EditText. Also the same thing would apply later. A table would show that number of textviews at the header.

Is there a way to do this by using some XML and some java? Because I believe by using only java it will be a pain to style different things.

Please let me know if you need further info.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can put all the attachment/looping logic in java but simply inflate existing xml resources - so no need to style, etc in the java layer.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the `visibility` attribute of a View.

If you have a fixed set of ui elements (say, 5 buttons) you can just include them in the layout and show them later with `setVisibility(View.Visible)`.

However, if you have a dynamic amount of elements (the user can chose from 1 to n buttons) then you will have to implement it in Java. You can still use XML layouts for parts of the work, but most stuff will have to be done by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample code , See if it helps you

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {

    LinearLayout main;
    private int id = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_count);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final int count = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText()
                        .toString());
                addEditText(count);
            }
        });

    }

    private void addEditText(int count) {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            LinearLayout editTextLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            editTextLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            main.addView(editTextLayout);

            EditText editText1 = new EditText(this);
            editText1.setId(id++);
            editTextLayout.addView(editText1);

        }
    }
}
```

and the layout test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_count"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To add style

```
editTextLayout.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
```

Comment: thanks guys.   Brontok, I understand your code. What I still cannot understand is after we add all these edittext using ur method, how can we have them styled using a predefined XML ?